# No url found for submodule path 'django/03_REL' in .gitmodules

Tags: django

`No url found for submodule path 'django/03_REL' in .gitmodules`

`The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128`

I'm encountering a build error in GitHub committing process.
The error messages are above.

I tried `git submodule -v status` and below is the result.

```
usage: git submodule [--quiet] [--cached]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] add [-b <branch>] [-f|--force] [--name <name>] [--reference <repository>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] status [--cached] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] init [--] [<path>...]      
   or: git submodule [--quiet] deinit [-f|--force] (--all| [--] <path>...)
   or: git submodule [--quiet] summary [--cached|--files] [--summary-limit <n>] [commit] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] foreach [--recursive] <command>
   or: git submodule [--quiet] sync [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] absorbgitdirs [--] [<path>...]
```

The file includes a .gitignore file and I don't know if it is a matter of a .gitignore file or if there are other reasons.